# How can I order post entries in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I made my post model where I store all the post info, like the title, the body, the tags an so on. And I linked it to my index template with a for loop:

```
<!-- Blog Post -->
      {% for blog in object_list %}
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 id="post_title" class="card-title">{{blog.title}}</h2>
            <div id="post_body" class="card-text">{{blog.formatted_markdown|safe}}</div>
            <a href="details/{{blog.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <p id="foot_page">{{blog.date}}</p>
            <a id="foot_page" href="#">{{blog.author}}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

And when I run my server the post appear on the blog ordered by pub_date ascending, so the new ones appear delow the old ones.

What can I do to make the newest post appear on top?

Here's my Post model class if it's useful:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = MarkdownxField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Raúl Chirinos')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def formatted_markdown(self):
        return markdownify(self.body)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I managed the views within the urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from raulchirinos.models import Post

app_name = 'raulchirinos'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin-site'),
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(model=Post, template_name='raulchirinos/index.html'), name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=Post, template_name='raulchirinos/post_template/post.html'), name='post_details'),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your views?

Comment: Done! My views file is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a meta class to the models and set the sort according to your requirement.

**Ex:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = MarkdownxField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Raúl Chirinos')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    @property
    def formatted_markdown(self):
        return markdownify(self.body)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options depending on the level where you need the ordering to happen:

1. Set a Meta subclass to your Post model with the `ordering` attribute set to order by `date` descending. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]
```

2. Order the data from the modle in your view before passing it onto the context.
3. Reverse the for loop in the template.

Of course the best option is probably the first one, since it's likely that you want this ordering in any case when you retrieve multiple Posts.